# Excel VBA Coding to scrape data, I am stuck

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

First of all I would like to thank this community for the amazing website. I am completely new to the coding world and excel vba. After learning about the possibilities in excel I started my journey to automate our daily data entry that we do here at our business. I have been able over the past few weeks to put some codes together that can access a secured website and generate the report I need based on the date I enter. However now I am stuck in how to actually pull the table values into excel. I have attached a few pictures. Right now the the third and fourth

Comment: I'd recommend pasting your code into the body of your question - easier for us to help and thus more likely you'll get a response

Comment: Thank you RGA I went ahead and posted my code. Thank you

Comment: Matteo NNZ has a very good answer. You'll want to be reasonably familiar with HTML coding (and CSS really).  You need to find something unique that identifies the data you are pulling, then you can pull it in.

Comment: please don't post pictures of code. Use the snippet tool available via [edit] to insert relevant html.

Comment: It would help if you can verify if the classnames and ids of the relevant items are dynamic or static i.e. do they change over time/with different report selections? They look like they could be dynamic. I can think of at least one sensible and flexible approach to this if you can share the html for the whole report page using https://pastebin.com/

Comment: @QHarr I posted my excel code already or are you referring to the code from the website? Sorry learning as I go along this was my first post. YES the class and IDs are dynamic

Comment: code from the website i.e. the html. The snippet tool icon looks like a document with  <> angle brackets on. You paste html in the top left square. Can you also confirm if the number of rows in the table(s) remain constant.

Comment: @Qharr I believe the number of rows do not remain constant as sometimes we have different sales and the report can sometimes between 2 to 4 pages long. Trying to figure out the snippet tool real quick as soon as I figure out I will try to post it.

Comment: @QHarr how can I copy all the html from the website to there?

Comment: The answer given is good though I would load set the ie.document to an htmldocument variable and pass that to the function (just a personal preference). If you select the opening html tag at the top of the document <html> and right click it > copy element > that should copy all the html.

Comment: @QHarr I got some of the snippet in there please let me know if that helps

Comment: @QHarr can you please check the code? Thank you

Comment: I looked but it is only part. I would like to see the entire html via pastebin.com

Comment: @QHarr https://pastebin.com/p9m5tMMw finally lol

Comment: @QHarr can you please check the code, I posted it on pastebin

Answer (score 2):

I would approach it with a function which takes in input two parameters:

- The Internet Explorer instance
- The label you want to scrape (e.g. `NET SALES`)

... and returns as `String` the desired value. 
Unfortunately I can't help much without having the real HTML and being able to test, so this is my **blind** attempt (get inspired, but don't expect to copy/paste and that the code will work):

```
Private Function getValueByLabel(ByVal ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, ByVal label As String) As String
    Dim listOfRows As Object: Set listOfRows = ie.document.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    Dim cellsInsideARow As Object 
    For Each tRow In listOfRows
        Set cellsInsideARow = tRow.getElementsByTagName("td")
        If cellsInsideARow(2).getElementsByTagName("div")(1).innerText = label Then
            getValueByLabel = cellsInsideARow(3).getElementsByTagName("div")(1).innerText
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next tRow
    getValueByLabel = "N/A"
End Function
```

Basically the function above is:

- Getting the list of `tr` (rows) loaded into the `document.body` of the `InternetExplorer` instance you passed through
- For each of them, checking if the `.innerText` of the 3rd `td` (cell) element is equal to the `label` you want to scrape (in your case `NET SALES`)
- If it's the case, returns the function with the `.innerText` of the 4th `td` element
- Else, returns `N/A`

You would use the function by just calling it with the good parameters from your macro, for example:

```
Range("A1") = "NET SALES"
Range("B1") = getValueByLabel(IE, Range("A1").Value)
```

P.s. the reason why I did a function is that you can re-use the same code for any element being into the same table, by just passing the wished label (`NET SALES` rather than `GROSS SALES` etc.)

Comment: how can I get it to enter the data into my sheet 1 cell A17? And do I need to post that code for every label I need? I am sorry I am a total noob on this stuff just trying to understand it correctly. Can you write the actual code to generate the net sales and value or is the above what I need to write in?

Comment: @MohamadBallout, I can't code something working without having real access to the code. All I can do is look at the HTML structure you posted and try my guess. In my answer you already have what you need, if you write `Range("B1") = getValueByLabel(IE, "NET SALES")` in your macro you'll get the value of NET SALES in cell B1, if you write `Range("B2") = getValueByLabel(IE, "GROSS SALES")` you'll have the value of GROSS SALES in `B2`, etc.

Comment: Matteo, I understand. I copied that same code in but is not returning any value

Comment: do you do any private coding? via team view or something? @Matteo NNZ

Comment: @MohamadBallout, as I was saying, you can't expect to copy/paste it and make it work. Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the function, then move step by step (F8) and check what object you're reading. The logic is that one, but the elements you access depend on the actual DOM of your HTML page that I only see in a picture.

Comment: @MohamadBallout no, this site is not for free-lancing but just free knowledge sharing. I unfortunately don't do that, but I highly suggest you to spare some money by simply following the breakpoint suggestion I gave you above.

Comment: Sorry was not trying to get free lancing. I am going to try to insert a breakpoint looking up how to do that right now. Thank you again for your help I appreciate it.

Comment: @MohamadBallout have a look at [this page](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/vba_debug2013.php). If you're learning to code, learning how to debug is vital. Coding without debugging is like driving with a blindfold. Good study :)

Comment: thank you for the link and your help, I will make sure to read that.

Comment: @QHarr you’re right, I’ve fixed the issue. MohamadBallout, you might want to check the code after edit proposed.

Comment: I tried your code with adjusting minor things but I am not generating any data into the cells. Can you check the html I posted ?

Comment: @MohamadBallout the HTML you posted is not much different than what you posted yesterday, I would need the website. Did you try debugging as I was telling you yesterday? This is really what you should be doing to fix this kind of issue. The code is structured properly, but you will have to run it step by step and checking each variable you define to figure out where the concrete issue is.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/p9m5tMMw  here it is sorry took me a while was trying to figure it out.

Comment: The report that gets generated sometimes has two or three pages, and you have to click to go to the next page. It is dynamic

Comment: I am still stuck guys if somebody can take a look at the pastebin html link I posted I would appreciate it.